# Do I generate multiple controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

I'm on the rails learning journey and am going about making my first rails app. It's a very simple app where users can create posts on a variety of topics.

I generated my first scaffold for a page I want to have called 'London' (rails generate scaffold london location:string content:text). Users of the site can post a post and location of a place to visit in London.

Then I wanted to replicate this functionality for 'Paris'. Do I generate a new scaffold or go about it a different way? Some advice would be appreciated.

Also the url gets pluralized (mywebsite.com/londons). I added

`resources :londons, :path => "london"`

which changed the url but when I go to make a post I get a No route matches [POST] "/londons" error. Anyone got a fix for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Although not always the case, initially you can think of a controller corresponding to one data table. Do you have a data table called "london" and another called "paris"? If not, then perhaps you have a data table which has an attribute called "place" which could be "london," "paris," etc. That would be a single controller "place" and then you'd manage the views accordingly. You certainly wouldn't want to have to create a new controller every time you add a place. You need to think about the data and teh relations in the data first, then generate the code from that.

Answer (score 1):

well instead of generating controllers for each city a better way could be to create relationships between models.For example you could create a cities and a locations scaffold then inside your city model you can do

```
has_many :locations
```

and inside you locations model you can do

```
belongs_to :city
```

that way you wouldn't need to create new scaffolds for every city.You can read up on how to use relationships from the guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks Brock90! I'll read up on using relationships and see what I can do!

Answer (score 0):

Well probably You want to generalise things first :)

What You actually need are *pages* (or maybe topics, articles). You can implement Page model that will have such attributes as title (which can be London, Paris etc).

The You will introduce a PagesController. `index` action will lead to a list of pages, `show` will render particular page.

In your routes You will do something like this:

```
resources :pages
```

Comment: So in the PagesController I have models for each City page? I may have completely missed the point here :) And then I guess I manually add the view/show/create pages etc for each?

Comment: You told that ` It's a very simple app where users can create posts on a variety of topics`, so I assumed that topics won't be limited to places. That's why I proposed to generalise under this name. 

I encourage You to go through some book ("Rails Agile development" is not bad as a starter) or go through this tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.

At this point it seems that You know too little to independently create this app, leave it as the second and build one proposed in tutorial. You can't build a skyscraper or even small house without a good foundation.